# scrollTop on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I've multiple elements with the class "accordeon" on my website. If the user is clicking one of them, the browser should scroll this elements to the top of the browser. By some reason, the "scroll-function" does not work very well: I seems that the browser just randomly scrolls.

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.accordeon').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( this ).offset().top - 80
    }, 200);
});
```

[Have a look on my website (just click on one of the topics)!](http://diakonie.headonline.de/kinder-und-jugend/ein-haus-fuer-alle-kinder/inhalte-basics/)

Comment: Probably because the offset top is changing while the other elements collapse? Looks to me like it is taking the initial value before the other elementt has collapsed. Naturally that isn't right anymore when the scrolling starts.

Comment: Seems to be working fine, what exactly is "not working very well"?